# I keep getting a 404 error when trying to use echo3D's REST API

Tags: rest, 3d, augmented-reality, usdz

I am playing around with echo3D's rest API (hoping to load download some models into the apple Pro Vision simulator).
I am attempting to use this endpoint to download a USDZ file but I always seem to get an error (HTTP Status 404 – Not Found):

> https://api.echo3d.com/download/model?key=MYKEY&secKey=MYSECRETKEY&entry=6af76ce2-2f57-4ed0-82d8-42652f0eddbe&fileFormat=usdz&convertMissing=true
> based on the docs (https://docs.echo3d.com/download):
> https://api.echo3D.com/download/model?key=<API_KEY>&entry=<ENTRY_ID>&fileFormat=<FILE_FORMAT>&convertMissing=true
>
> HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
> Type Status Report
> Message /download/model
> Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
> Apache Tomcat/8.5.23

I checked the docs, no luck.

I followed the docs and I was supposed to successfully download my USDZ file.

Answer (score 0):

The Download API endpoint has been changed to `/download-model`. Use:

```
https://api.echo3D.com
/download-model?key=<API_KEY>&entry=<ENTRY_ID>&fileFormat=<FILE_FORMAT>&convertMissing=true
```

See more [here](https://docs.echo3d.com/download).